# outage capacity of K user fading channel

Tags: digital-communications, mimo

Suppose you have $K$ users, each seeing a point to point fading channel with $n$ receive diversity. So the rate of the kth user is at most $\log(1+ SNR|h_k|^2)$. Now suppose, each user transmits at rate $R$, then the probability of outage is $P(\cup log(1+ SNR|h_k|^2) < R)$ (ie, the system is in outage when at least one of the users can't support their rate $R$). From this, we can calculate the $\epsilon$ symmetric outage capacity which I found to be approximately equal to the $\epsilon / k$ outage capacity of the point to point channel with $n$ receive diversity.

However, my textbook says it's equal to the $\epsilon$ outage capacity of the point to point channel with $n$ receive diversity.

I'm confused how they arrived at the result? For reference [https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/papers/book121004.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Edntse/papers/book121004.pdf) page 506 at the bottom page.